# LAMP on Ubuntu creates write protected files

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I have set up a Ubuntu LAMP server, and everything is working fine, however, I have a PHP script that allows the user to upload files to a directory within the www directory. The files saved via PHP are chmod 644.

How can I change the setting so that the files saved on the server are chmod 755 by default?

Answer (score -2):

1. Educate yourself as to what a [`umask`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) is.
2. Use the [`umask()`](http://www.php.net/function.umask) function.

Comment: Hi Sammitch, thanks for the suggestion. What I dont understand though, is that I have copied my code from a shared hosting where everything worked correctly, including the PHP write permissions, over to the Ubuntu server I created. I think I need to change the settings of my PHP installation. This is the first time I have created my own server so I am sure there is something in the settings that I have missed. Is there a global php setting I can change that will affect how PHP writes files on the server?

Comment: @Ronnyvdb the umask configuration is part of the *OS*, not PHP. Also, having been employed as an administrator for various hosting environments the last 10 years, one thing that most PHP devs need to be aware of is that unless two servers are *literal clones* of each other there are going to be differences, and you cannot simply expect to load your PHP app onto a different server and have it "just work".

Comment: I understand the clones won't work on different servers, I just thought I would mention that my code does work :). So I set the UMASK to 0002 in UBUNTU, the umask command in the terminal confirms this is set, But the files created via PHP still have the wrong permissions :(